# how do contravariant 2-functors preserve adjunctions?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I know that covariant 2-functors preserve adjunctions. Do contravariant 2-functors preserve the order left-right of the adjoints, or do they reverse it?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "contravariant", because there are two compositions in a 2-category.

Comment: Given $F: A \to B$ and $C$ in $Cat$, I want to know whether the functor $[F,C] : [B,C] \to [A,C]$ (precomposing by $F$) preserves the order of an adjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a 2-category, there are two different compositions (traditionally called horizontal and vertical) which can be reversed independently. If you reverse just one of the compositions, then the handedness of adjunctions is reversed. For example, for a fixed object $C$, $\mathrm{Hom} (-, C)$ reverses only horizontal composition and will send left adjoints in your 2-category to right adjoints in $\mathfrak{Cat}$.

Of course, if you reverse both compositions, then the handedness of adjunctions is preserved. For example, $[(-)^\mathrm{op}, C]$ preserves left adjoints.